# How can I update/rebind variable without changing the value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a RESTful server which have several images.
I am using below URL to get an user's profile image.

```
https://example.com/users/jake/profile_image
```

My Typescript:

```
...
export class SomePage {

    // this variable is binded to img tag in html
    profile_image: string = 'https://example.com/users/jake/profile_image'; 

    changeProfileImageInServer() {
        // this method changes profile image in the server. 
        // But, the new image has the same URL.
    }
}
```

The value of variable 'profile_image' doesn't need to change because the new image in the server has the same URL. but I want to change image in html because the profile image has changed. What should I do from now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. How the image changed and the url not?

Comment: @FunStuff My API server maintains only the last profile image for each user. When I put a new image in that URL, the new image is replaced into the same URL.

Comment: Assume that the user named 'jake' is trying to change his own profile image. My API server will accept the new profile image of jake's in the URL. After that, we can access the new profile image in the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, thinking someone will have the same question with mine.

I also uploaded this question in the forum of the ionic framework.
One of the moderators of Ionic framework answered my question.

> this will not work because of the image cache of the browser/webview.
>   You should store the timestamp/date, when the image was changed --> so
>   you can add this timestamp to the image url:
>
> ```
> 'https://example.com/users/jake/profile_image?' + TIMESTAMP
> ```

from https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-update-rebind-variable-without-changing-the-value/73436/2?u=jeongmincha

Comment: Just a comment, answer should contain code or actual answer, not just a link, as links can change :)

Comment: @ASomeOneJ Thank you for correcting me. I will add the content of the answer.